# UITableView access mberOfSectionsInTableView twice and crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

As I am loading a UITableView it access numberOfSectionsInTableView: two times and crash the app with “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. I have never experienced this before.

Should numberOfSectionsInTableView: be accessed twice when doing the initial load of the tableview?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInTableView");  
   // Return the number of sections.
   NSLog(@"Count: %i", [self.playerArray count]);  
   return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section         {
  NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection");  
    // Return the number of rows in the section.  
    NSLog(@"time for return");  
    return [self.playerArray count];
}
```

Response is:

> 2010-11-20 19:35:06.459 FamQuiz_v2[10151:207] numberOfSectionsInTableView
>   Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
>   2010-11-20 19:35:12.408 FamQuiz_v2[10151:207] Count: 2
>   (gdb) continue
>   2010-11-20 19:35:28.918 FamQuiz_v2[10151:207] numberOfSectionsInTableView
>   Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
>   Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make sure your playerArray property is correctly retained.

I'm not sure why that method is called twice, but there is nothing that says it can't or won't be called multiple times.

Comment: I did put [playerArray retain] in "numberOfSectionsInTableView" and it worked. I would guess the reason was that it was accessed twice.

Comment: that's probably not the right place to put your retain.  check that it's retained properly when it's created.

Comment: can you define "retained properly"? As this is the first time i have experienced this i have never thought about the need to do this.